# How to put bitmap in azure sqlserver

Tags: android, sql-server, azure

I need to put bitmap in azure sql server from android. I have columns that are strings work with my other data but not with bitmaps. What should my azure sqlserver column type be and what should I try storing the bitmap as?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use varbinary(max) and convert the bitmap to a byte array.

ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx

A better practice might be to store the image in blob storage and write the url to the image blob in the database.

ref: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-java-how-to-use-blob-storage/